# SQL Server: how to look statistics of queries to a table

Tags: sql-server, statistics, database-administration

I would like to find out which queries are made to a table most often.
Where these statistics are stored in SQL Server?

Comment: You should look up how extended events work and how to configure an extended event session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using Extended Events, SQL Server provides access to these statistics in System Dynamic Management Views (DMVs).  These views are transient and not persisted through restarts.

There are many examples of using these views as an adhoc mechansim for finding which queries are made to a table.

A few to get you started:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats T1
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan (T1.plan_handle )

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats T1
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_SQL_text (T1.SQL_handle )
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql

Depending on the version of SQL Server, you may wish to use the Management Data Warehouse, Query Store, or a 3rd-party monitoring tool to persist this data to a management database.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-collection/configure-the-management-data-warehouse-sql-server-management-studio